# bash treats string as a directory

Tags: string, bash, replace

I have a string like "/directory/username" and I want to use a bash script to change this to "/directory-username". This is what I have tried:

```
path="/directory/username"
path=$($path | sed -r 's/(.*)\//\1-/')
```

Here is the output:

```
bash: /directory/username: No such file or directory
```

What is it that I have failed to understand?

Comment: The thing before `|` needs to be a *command,* not just the data you want to feed into the pipe. This is a common beginner error. (The [lack of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) is another.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$path` will execute as a command in your expression.

Try `path=$(echo "$path" | sed -r 's/(.*)\//\1-/')` to treat `$path` as a parameter.

There is no need to escape the pattern split character. To make the command more elegant, you could use `#` to replace `/` as the pattern split character in this case, like `path=$(echo "$path" | sed -r 's#(.*)/#\1-#')`

Comment: You should double-quote variable references to avoid weird parsing problems, e.g. `echo "$path"` instead of just `echo $path`.